# Adding a child view at particular location in parent view

Tags: android

I need to draw a child view containing a rectangle and button  on top of the content view at particular location on the parent (content view).

How can I do this?  Did not find an explicit way to set origin of child view?

Answer (score -1):

It depends. If you are talking about placing the rectangle at an absolute position, remember that android devices come with many many screensizes.

Comment: Yes, i can calculate the absolute coordinate of the rectangle.  Or I can also calculate as a relative to the parent view.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a relative view, then set the margin around the rectangle to the offset you want. More info on relative views is here: http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html